# Merge multiple data frames in a specific order R

Tags: r, merge, sequence, lapply

I have 2 lists containing 5 data frames each, and they are in a specific order ;

```
list_1<-list("A","B","C","D")

list_2 <-list(("Aa","Bb","Cc","Dd")
```

I need to left_join A to Aa, B to Bb and so on, therefore reduce is not a option as I'm aware. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I though about using lapply but I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are joining the dataset in the corresponding order, it would be good to use `Map`.  Assuming that we are storing the object names as strings in another object ('list_1' or 'list_2'), it is better to have it as a `vector` instead of `list` and then do `mget` to get the values of the objects

```
Map(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE), mget(list_1), mget(list_2))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(mget(list_1), mget(list_2), left_join)
```

#### data

```
list_1<- c("A","B","C","D")
list_2 <- c("Aa","Bb","Cc","Dd")
```

Comment: tks for your support. I tried to build a third list with the merges using   ________list_3<- map2(mget(list_1), mget(list_2), left_join)
  however I gor the following error:Error in mget(list_1) : invalid first argument

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira  Can you check the output of `mget(list_1)`  I am assuming that `list_1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")` instead of `list_1 <- list("A", "B", "C", "D")`

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira  I checked with a reproducible example and it is working fine. `A <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:3], col2 = rnorm(3))
> B <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[2:6], col2 = rnorm(5))
> list_1 <- c("A", "B")
> Aa <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[2:4], col3 = rnorm(3)); Bb <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[2:3], col3 =rnorm(2))
> list_2 <- c("Aa", "Bb");map2(mget(list_1), mget(list_2), left_join)`

Comment: @akrum , Worked:) thanks what I had to do was to change from list() to c()..............Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira  Yes, you have to change or `unlist` to make it a vector and the `mget` will result in a `list` of `data.frame` from that vector list of object name